# update textbox on 2nd form from threaded sub not working VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have two forms: Form1, and StreamFrm.
From a threaded sub on Form1 I need to update textboxes on StreamFrm.
I tried the following:

```
Private Sub timerTicks() Handles EventTimer.Tick
    If IsCheckingTable = False Then
        StreamFrm.Puts7.Text = "test from Form1 : timerticks"
        Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf CheckTableForNewRecords), IsCheckingTable)
    End If
    Timertxt.Text = Date.Now
End Sub
Private Sub CheckTableForNewRecords(IsCheckingTable)
    IsCheckingTable = True
    swR.Restart()
    swR.Start()
    PR = LR
    SQL.GETlastrcrd(QueryLR, LR)
    NR = LR - PR
    strm()
    UpdateLastrcrdFrm(LR)
    UpdatePrvLrcdrFrm(PR)
    UpdateNewrcrdFrm(NR)
    If NR > 0 Then
        Dim QueryRR As String = "SELECT * from(select ROW_NUMBER() over (Order by StreamingID ) as row, " & _
                                "StreamingID,WatchlistID,symbol,Bid,Ask,Last,High,Low,PrevClose,Volume,TradeTime," & _
                                "QuoteTime,TradeDate,QuoteDate,Volatility,OpenInterest,UnderlyingSymbol,CallPut,TradeVolume,TradeAmount,Trade,LastSize from optionstream) " & _
                                "as StreamingID where StreamingID between " & (PR + 1) & " AND " & LR
        SQL.GetTrades(QueryRR)
    End If
    UpdateTEchecktrades()
    IsCheckingTable = False
End Sub
Private Sub strm()
    If StreamFrm.Puts6.InvokeRequired Then
        StreamFrm.Puts6.Invoke(New action(AddressOf strm))
    Else
        StreamFrm.Puts6.Text = "test from Form1 : ChecktableFornewrecords"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateLastrcrdFrm(LR)
    If LastrcrdFRM.InvokeRequired Then
        LastrcrdFRM.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateLastrcrdFrm), LR)
    Else
        LastrcrdFRM.Text = LR
    End If
End Sub
```

It updates StreamFrm.Puts7.Text = "test from Form1 : timerticks"  just fine; it's in the same thread.

From sub CheckTableForNewRecords(IsCheckingTable) which is threaded, I call sub strm() which checks whether StreamFrm.Puts6 needs an invoke before writing text to it.
This does not work, no errors, but no text in the text box.

However  LastrcrdFRM.Text = LR does work. But this text box is on Form1.

So how do I update the text box on Form StreamFrm?
I am using the same invoke method as with Form1, so why doesnt it work?

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, InvokeRequired doesn't work as expected when called on the control.  You need to call it on the Form.

```
Private Sub strm()
    If StreamFrm.InvokeRequired Then
        StreamFrm.Invoke(New action(AddressOf strm))
    Else
        StreamFrm.Puts6.Text = "test from Form1 : ChecktableFornewrecords"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but same result; StreamFrm.Puts.Text   remains blank. no errors.